# CentOS test page and .htaccess

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, htaccess

When I use the line below in the `.htaccess` file, I get the Apache CentOS test page.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite condition checks if the requested URI matches a real folder. If not, the following rewrite rule will be applied.

In other words, it means that if the directory in the browser doesn't exist then proceed to the next rewrite rule below.

You should probably read up on how mod_rewrite works in Apache. Here's a good tutorial to get you started, titled: [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://www.datakoncepts.com/seo), and also the official documents, [Apache Module mod_rewrite v2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).